# How to get new Access Token using MSAL with the help of a valid Access Token in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am trying to figure out a way but not able to find any solution anywhere. We have .Net based application (REST API service) where we need to get a new token with the help of current access token before it expires. I am able to find examples of getting a token using MSAL but it requires user to put in the password to get it. However, our service does not have any UI so it has to get the new token silently. We have the current valid access token if there is a way to get the new one with the help of that. I am pretty new to `C#`.

```
var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                 .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, TenantId).Build();
var accounts = publicClientApplication.GetAccountsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var result = publicClientApplication
                 .AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                 .ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

tried the above snippet but it does not use the current valid access token to get a new one.